# Android ExoPlayer - How to run ExoPlayer in background thread?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, android-media3

I'm using Jetpack Compose, and ExoPlayer to play video files. When I navigate to the Playback screen, the UI freezes while init/prepare ExoPlayer. I see the log, it has a lot of "skipped XXX frames". I found how to configure ExoPlayer to run on a background thread using HandlerThread. But the next issue is androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView cannot be used to display Video and the app crashes. So, how do we implement ExoPlayer run in a background thread?

Comment: You can refer this article: https://blog.canopas.com/live-streaming-and-audio-equalizer-with-exoplayer-in-jetpack-compose-a74fb5eb93cb that provides steps for setting up exoplayer with initialization and releasing steps.

Comment: I tested and saw exoPlayer.prepapre() block UI thread. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/ZahraHeydari/MusicPlayer).

Repo Link : https://github.com/ZahraHeydari/MusicPlayer